# How to get a collections attached schema with Meteors aldeed:simpleschema and mdg:validated-method

Tags: meteor, methods, simple-schema

I want to created an automatically validated method like the one [here](https://github.com/meteor/validated-method#using-simpleschema) but using a schema already defined and attached to a collection.

To this end is there a way to extract a collections attached schema, something like:

```
  validate: Books.getSchema().validator(),
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's `Books.simpleSchema()` this returns the schema object attached to the given collection